# mmenu jumps to the right position

Tags: mmenu

My open mmenu button is located in the centered div (`width: 1300px; margin: 0 auto;`).

When open mmenu button is clicked, dropdown mmenu container shows up absolute at `top: 0, left:  0;` and jumps to the calculated position after half a second delay.

How to prevent this behaviour?

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/118622/

Comment: please add your full code

Comment: Here you can see what I mean (code edited to make the problem even more visible) https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/118622/